# Gitlab-cl server and memory usage

Tags: memory, gitlab, centos6

we are running gitlab-cl 10.0.1 installed from repository on centos 6.9

We have a physical server with 65GB of RAM.
We had slow performances on the web interface, so looking at the memory we saw that the server is swapping a bit and all the memory is used.

There is no active process using it and free -m confirms it is cached :

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
 Mem:         64412      64179        232        140          1        176
 -/+ buffers/cache:      64001        410
 Swap:        15999       2679      13320
```

The strange thing is that all memory is allocated on DirectMap2M

```
cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       65957916 kB
MemFree:          242364 kB
Buffers:            1132 kB
Cached:           193548 kB
SwapCached:       853032 kB
Active:          6302692 kB
Inactive:        1729836 kB
Active(anon):    6276560 kB
Inactive(anon):  1704824 kB
Active(file):      26132 kB
Inactive(file):    25012 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      16383996 kB
SwapFree:       13580524 kB
Dirty:              1576 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       7595904 kB
Mapped:           162376 kB
Shmem:            144312 kB
Slab:           57184100 kB
SReclaimable:      35132 kB
SUnreclaim:     57148968 kB
KernelStack:       12912 kB
PageTables:        59144 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    49362952 kB
Committed_AS:   18168608 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      395428 kB
VmallocChunk:   34323721400 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   3260416 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        7652 kB
DirectMap2M:    67088384 kB
```

Do you know why this is happening?
Is that normal with gitlab?

I read about few commands to remove cache from the memory :

```
# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Are they safe to run on a production machine running gitlab?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Can't say exactly why all memory is used up but the fact is that it is. At first I expected the standard https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ but I can see that in your case you are actually using 64001 kb of memory.
The commands listed are pointless, what they do is just delete disk blocks that are cached in memory causing an io hit next time same block is needed.

To find out what's going on you need to see what process that uses up all the memory. It is several ways to get that info

```
ps -e -o pid,vsz,comm= | sort -n -k 2
```

or to get the arguments also

```
ps -e -o pid,vsz,command= | sort -n -k 2|cut -b1-$COLUMNS
```

you can start "top" and hit uppercase "M" to sort by memory user.